# List construction in Haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor

I have the following recursive function for project euler [question no. 74](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=74):

```
chain n | n `elem` xs = length xs
        | otherwise = (chain (sumFac n)) : xs
fac n = foldl (*) 1 $ enumFromTo 1 n
sumFac n = sum $ map fac $ decToList n
```

Except I don't know the correct syntax to construct a list on `chain n` so that it builds up a list of `xs` and then returns the length of `xs` once a number appears again in the list of `xs` and begins to loop.

How would I correct my chain function to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a helper function:

```
chain n = go [n]
  where go xs | next `elem` xs = reverse $ next : xs
              | otherwise      = go (next:xs)
          where next = sumFac $ head xs

fac = product . enumFromTo 1

sumFac = sum . map fac . map digitToInt . show
```

As you can see, you were close to what you wanted, but you blurred the two together.

For fun, I tossed in point-free equivalents of `fac` and `sumFac`.

Here's a point-free definition that uses a [view pattern](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) (but, alas, seems to tickle [#2395](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2395)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

chain = head . filter hasDup . tail . inits . iterate sumFac
  where hasDup (reverse -> (x:xs)) = x `elem` xs
```

Comment: I'm not very well versed in the ways of point free notation yet. Is there a simple explanation other than syntactic sugar more powerful than `$`?

Comment: @Jonno: `\x -> f (g x)` == `\x -> (f . g) x` == `f . g` -- hence removing the "point" `x`, making it point-free.

Comment: @gbacon: Why do you need the view pattern, anyways?  `chain n = let l = iterate sumFac n in snd $ head $ filter (uncurry elem) $ zip l $ inits l` ... though I guess that's not point-free.

Comment: Aha!  With `Control.Arrow`, `chain = snd . head . filter (uncurry elem) . uncurry zip . (id &&& inits) . iterate sumFac` becomes point-free.

Answer (score 1):

I think your "chain" function is very confused.  You need to rethink it.  You use a value "xs" in it that does not seem to be in scope.  Where does "xs" come from?  Presumably it should be an argument.

A better approach would be to build up the infinite list of numbers generated by the problem, and then detect loops within it.  You can get the infinite list for starting value "n" using

```
numberSequence n = iterate sumFac n
```

Then look for cycles.  You have to check each number against all the preceeding numbers.  A simple but inefficient way is to build up a list as you go, checking each number against the current list, and then prepending the number on to the list in a recursive call.  A more efficient solution would be to use Data.Set.

By the way, fac n = product [1..n].  Your version works, but its unecessarily verbose.  (Actually if you substitute the definition of "product" and desugar "[1..n]" you get your version).

Comment: i used `foldl'` because for the memory optimisation. It's pretty much guaranteed to never cause a stack overflow.

Comment: I suggest reading this article: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27, my function differs from the normal `product =  foldl (*) 1` by using the strict fold `foldl`.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if it's this simple but you didn't specify that you wanted a head and a tail instead of the whole list in the params.

```
chain [n:xs] | n `elem` xs = length xs
             | otherwise = chain (sumFac n) : xs
fac n = foldl (*) 1 $ enumFromTo 1 n
sumFac n = sum $ map fac $ decToList n
```

I don't have decToList so I didn't test if this works or not. Cool job of it though, I learned a lot reading this.

Comment: decToList just makes a number into a list of numbers, I think the head and tail of the list in this instance is irrelevant

Comment: if you're using xs then head vs tail is pretty important. At least thats the first error I had when trying this out.